# Wall sound proofing - hanging rows of sound proof "curtains"

Tags: sound-proofing

The building's structure is concrete, as is the floor/roof. The wall to my neighbor is brick; so a lot of noise comes through - TVs, crying babies etc.

I've seen a number of options for constructing various wooden frames with layers of sound insulation; but am wondering if just hanging "curtains" of sound isolation foam could work well. The wall in question is pictured below, and the columns on each side are concrete. Discussions of wooden frames have various approaches to decoupling the sound isolation from the wall being soundproofed - and using curtains seems like a good way to tackle this to me.

Of course; if I ever wanted to use the wall as a wall; I would need a final frame + drywall; but there is enough space to put these on the outside of the concrete pillars.

Any thoughts; comments; suggestions welcome

[image]

Thanks
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound isolation foam doesn't work like that. It's designed to remove reverb, not block sounds. What you want are "soundproof curtains". These are designed to be heavy curtains that can actually block sound. Basically anything else with mass will have similar effects, but these are a good way to block off the entire wall. You mount them the same way you would mount regular curtains, though with more attention paid to weight. If you have a bunch of books, sticking your bookcases against that wall would also help.

Doing this correctly basically involves opening up the wall and decoupling your apartment from your neighbor's. I'll assume that isn't an option.

Comment: Thanks!
When I say sound isolation foam; I had in mind products similar to https://www.amazon.com/12-Acoustic-Panels-Studio-Wedges/dp/B00TP7C9YY/ref=bmx_1/135-9219536-4801510?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00TP7C9YY&pd_rd_r=16f2aee4-82c4-4164-839c-3dffbe366dbd&pd_rd_w=3USe6&pd_rd_wg=UvFfc&pf_rd_p=806524e0-5994-4c0d-9d36-11f6132400bc&pf_rd_r=ZBN2WKQB1HT03R9W94K7&psc=1&refRID=ZBN2WKQB1HT03R9W94K7 so are these unlikely to perform well at blocking sound?

Comment: Would https://www.amazon.com/dp/B008JHE1P6/ref=psdc_11975721_t4_B07FK5JYRN be good for curtains? Would attaching directly to the wall; or hanging just in front have different sound damping performances?

Comment: Acoustic panels/foam wedges are useless for soundproofing; don't bother with them. Mass loaded vinyl is actually useful, though usually mounted inside the wall. Not sure if they're suitable for wall-mounting. Acoustic curtains or soundproof curtains would look better if that's a consideration, though are more expensive.

Comment: If you have a choice, I'd mount your soundproofing material loosely, though it's more important that there aren't gaps around the outside or between sections.